# Sieve of Eratosthenes, generating primes. Problem with loops

Tags: java, loops, nested-loops, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm trying to generate n number of primes using the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm. I debugged it and saw that at some point it starts deleting numbers that had already been deleted. I can't what's the problem, but I can bet it's to do with my loops. Could you help pls?

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Part6 {

    public static List<Integer> primeSequence(int n) {
        List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(2, n).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

        for (int i = 2; i <= list.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j <= list.size(); j++) {
            if(j % i == 0)
                list.remove(j);
            }
        }
       return  list;
        }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(primeSequence(Integer.parseInt(args[0])));
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You don't want to remove elements from a `List` as you're iterating through it. It would be better to build a separate `List` with the elements you wish to remove and then use the `removeAll()` method.

Answer (score 0):

This is how **Sieve of Eratosthenes** works, it keeps marking all the multiples of `prime` numbers other than itself in the range.
For example, when we start with `i=2`, we marks *4, 6, 8, 10, 12, ...* as `composite` number.
Again for `i=3`, it will mark *6, 9, 12, 15, ...* as non-prime.
Please observe that `6` & `12` were marked twice. There are many more numbers which would be marked as composites multiple times. Hence this is normal.

Now, the above program has many issues as:

1. When you perform `list.remove(j)`, it actually removes the number at index `j` not the number `j` itself. So, to remove the composite number `j` we need to use `Integer.valueOf(j)`
2. Upper limit of the loops should not be `list.size()` as the size of list will keep decreasing as we keep removing the numbers. Hence, many numbers will be missed.

Below is the modified version of your code:

```java
        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j <= n; j++)
            {
                if (j % i == 0)
                {
                    list.remove(Integer.valueOf(j));
                }
            }
            System.out.println(list);
        }
```

Input: **100**
Output:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

Comment: Thanks!! Could you also help me with the modified version pls? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68210398/generating-primes-using-nested-loops-java-problem-with-loops