# Generating primes using nested loops (java). Problem with loops

Tags: java, arrays, nested-loops, primes

I already generated primes using the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm (I asked about it here [Sieve of Eratosthenes, generating primes. Problem with loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68198348/sieve-of-eratosthenes-generating-primes-problem-with-loops/68198886#68198886))

But now I have to do it using only an array and nested loops.
I tried to apply this approch https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/for-loop/generate-prime-numbers-with-for-loop/, but I can't get why it doesn't work correctly for me
I just want to check if a number is prime and add it to my array
Could u help me pls?

```
public class Part6 {

    public static  int[] primeSequence(int n) {
        int[] primes = new int[n];

        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            boolean isPrimeNumber = true;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < i; j++) {
            if(j % i == 0)
                isPrimeNumber = false;
            break;
            }
            if (isPrimeNumber)
                primes[i] = i;
        }
       return  primes;
        }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int number : primeSequence(Integer.parseInt(args[0]))) {
            System.out.print(number);
        }

    }
    
}
```

Comment: Your `for (int j` loop always breaks on the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing braces in your inner loop, your inner loop doesn't get executed (int j = i + 1; j < i!), the order of operands in the modulo operation is wrong and the inner loop should probably start at 2.

```
        for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
        if(i % j) == 0){
             isPrimeNumber = false;
             break; 
            }
        }
```

Comment: I added them, but the result is still 0023456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899

Comment: You might want to redo this exercise from scratch. ^^

Comment: Why? And how? :((

Comment: Just kidding. You probably got lost in some loop or so.
Does the updated answer help?

Answer (score 0):

If we start the second loop from `j=i+1` then we will miss many numbers which might be a divisor of the number `i`. So, to check if `i` is a prime or not we should start with `j=2` for every i-th iteration.
Also, inside every nested loop we are checking if `i` is `Prime` or not so, we should whether `i % j == 0` or not.

Here is a modified version:

```java
    public static  int[] primeSequence(int n)
    {
        int k = 0;
        int[] primes = new int[n];
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            boolean isPrimeNumber = true;
            for (int j = 2; j < i; j++)
            {
                if (i % j == 0)
                {
                    isPrimeNumber = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isPrimeNumber)
                primes[k++] = i;
        }
        return  primes;
    }
```